# How to delete a particular row in a sql table?

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get the row number of ID of a sql table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4206500/how-to-get-the-row-number-of-id-of-a-sql-table)

Say: i need to delete the 5th row, or the 6th or the 20th...???

Comment: but LIMIT deletes the first n rows... and not the nth row...

Comment: yes i am talking abt MySQL...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$lcv = 0;
$row_to_delete = x;

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result){
     if($lcv == $row_to_delete){
          mysql_query("DELETE");
     }

     $lcv++;
}
```

Comment: thanks Jose... that seems to be satisfactory...

Answer (score 4):

You can use `LIMIT` in a `DELETE` request if you are using MySQL ^^

EDIT: Sorry it's not enough

> The MySQL-specific LIMIT row_count option to DELETE tells the server the maximum number of rows to be deleted before control is returned to the client. This can be used to ensure that a given DELETE statement does not take too much time. You can simply repeat the DELETE statement until the number of affected rows is less than the LIMIT value.

Comment: This would be the preferred solution if the OP is indeed using MySQL.

Comment: It's why I precise it. I don't know about others DBMS.

Comment: @Kailash: LIMIT on MySQL takes two arguments.  `LIMIT 6,1` would delete 1 record, starting with the 6th.  However, if it makes it clearer, you can use the OFFSET keyword explicitly: `LIMIT 1 OFFSET 6`

Comment: @R.BEMROSE:  does offset work with delete.. coz i got an error...

Comment: @Kailash: As far as I can tell, it does.

Comment: @R.BEMROSE:  it does not.. checked nw.. only limit 1 and not even limit 1,1

Answer (score 4):

I don't think this is possible in MySQL. The problem you have is the row number is subjective based on how the data is ordered. If you order your data by column 1 in ascending order and then you order by column 1 by descending order, which is row 1?

Preferably your tables should have primary key id fields in which you can specify them to delete.

```
DELETE FROM *table* WHERE id = *id*
```

Comment: +1: Personally, I think this is a better solution, even if it's not strictly what the OP asked.

Comment: I agree, I just think the OP has good reason to do that.