# How to get the row number of ID of a sql table?

Tags: php, sql

suppose i need to print the 3rd, 5th, 9th, 20th, 34th and so on...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to delete a particular row in a sql table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4206240/how-to-delete-a-particular-row-in-a-sql-table)

Comment: Please add an better example.

Comment: Answer will also depend on what SQL provider you are using: SQLServer, Oracle, MySQL will probably have different methods of obtaining a row id.

Comment: Don't you imagine it'll be very similar to your earlier query about how to delete the 3rd, 5th, 9th, 20th, 34th and so on...

Comment: Rephrasing the question will still get the same answers  as the question is still basically the same. Could you describe what you are trying to achieve so we can better help you?

Comment: @Veign: I need to print only certain rows based on a string of values... that are known only dynamically...

Comment: @powtac: my scenario: I need to delete only a single row... there are several identical rows.. so using a delete with a where clause would delete all of them. Also, say there are 5 identical rows.. and i need to delete the third of those 5 rows...

Comment: @Veign: Actually the user provides a string of numbers the rows corresponding to which are to be printed back to him... i used a separate col... but without that?

Comment: @Veign: sorry not exactly... the primary key with several other fields are the same... so u can't use even a combination of fields...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rows, by position, have no real meaning in a database (at least I can't think of any).  Why do you care its actual row location?

How do you know that 3rd record is the record you want to delete?  Match an ID, match a phrase in another field, do something to uniquely identify the record as the record you want to access.  Doing this by it row location will not do this for you.

If you have five records that all match exactly and you only want to delete one then add the LIMIT 1 to the end of your DELETE statement.  If they are exact the row doesn't matter.  The 3rd or 5th or 7th wouldn't matter since they match your query exactly.  So delete one of your matching query.

Now it sounds as if you are showing users a table of data in some order, which may or may not be duplicated, and allowing them the option to delete a row.  You are taking the actual row location instead of storing the Primary Key with each displayed row.  Then when a user selects a delete, you would just use the attached Primary Key to the row and delete that row.

You say "the primary key with several other fields are the same" - That can't be true as you can't have to identical primary keys.  I'm now thinking you have some flaw in your database design.  Post a table schema and sample of exactly what you are doing.  No point continuing if you backed yourself into a corner with the design (which is sounds like)

(I can't comment on other posts so updates have to be edited in this post)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4206240/how-to-delete-a-particular-row-in-a-sql-table/4206344#4206344

Comment: that's what... I don't want to use a seperate field to store the row number or Serial No... Suppose there are 5 identical rows.. the user clicks on the 3 rd row and asks that to be deleted... a where query won't be efficient as it deletes the first row that matches the where clause or all rows that match it.. how is that i delete only the third row and leave all others intact..???

Comment: sorry what i meant was not the primary key .... i meant the key which i use in the where clause...

Comment: Simple.  You need to use a Primary Key.  Apply a Primary Key to the table and key off of that for deletes and updates.  The Primary Key is indexed by default so accessing the row will be efficient.  Don't fight the proper method.

Comment: so you wan't me to use a seperate field with an auto increment value...???

Comment: That would be an easy solution.  Yes.  Add an Auto-increment field.  You'll have no speed or performance issues.  It will actually be must faster for accessing the records directly.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a row number variable:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT t.*, 
        @rownum = @rownum + 1 AS rank
    FROM TABLE t, (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
    ORDER BY ID
    LIMIT 0, 34
) Q
WHERE rank in (3, 5, 9, 20, 34)
```

I'd try to use the `LIMIT` smartly otherwise it will scan your whole table every time.

---

Based on your description of your scenario...

> my scenario: I need to delete only a single row... there are several identical rows.. so using a delete with a where clause would delete all of them. Also, say there are 5 identical rows.. and i need to delete the third of those 5 rows...

You really need to be careful with this otherwise you delete the wrong rows. Think of a good criterium that would distinguish the rows that you want to delete from the other rows, say.. do you want to delete the newest, or all except the newest...

You can use an extended version of the @rownum trick to delete the Nth from each group.. but before I go into that it would be better to know more about your specific problem.

---

Ah now here comes the monkey out of the sleeve:

> Suppose there are 5 identical rows.. the user clicks on the 3 rd row and asks that to be deleted... a where query won't be efficient as it deletes the first row that matches the where clause or all rows that match it.. how is that i delete only the third row and leave all others intact..???

Forget all I said. You need an `AUTO_INCREMENT` field in your table, uniquely identifying your records. Then you can use `DELETE FROM table WHERE id = $id`. Thanks to OMG Ponies for the OP therapy ;)

Comment: dat seems ok... but hw do u use LIMIT while retrieving a row ID...

Comment: @Kailash: What does `LIMIT` have to do with getting row rank/position?

Comment: @littlegreen: LIMIT is zero based, like C based arrays.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: that's what i myself doubt... limit works with select and delete...

Comment: @Kailash: What's your point?  There's lots of syntax available to use.

Comment: Suppose there are 5 identical rows.. the user clicks on the 3 rd row and asks that to be deleted... a where query won't be efficient as it deletes the first row that matches the where clause or all rows that match it.. how is that i delete only the third row and leave all others intact..???

Comment: @OMG Ponies:Suppose there are 5 identical rows.. the user clicks on the 3 rd row and asks that to be deleted... a where query won't be efficient as it deletes the first row that matches the where clause or all rows that match it.. how is that i delete only the third row and leave all others intact..???

Comment: @Kailash: Then you need a primary key (IE: auto_increment) for the table, not rank/position because the rank/position is dependent on data at the time

Comment: @OMG Ponies: so u want me to use a separate column with the row ID i.e. auto increment value...

Answer (score 0):

OFFSET part of LIMIT clause works with a SELECT query.

What do you want to do??

Comment: @powtac: I need to print only certain rows based on a string of values... that are known only dynamically...

Answer (score 0):

Rows in an SQL table are not in any particular order.  You can order them by a specific field, like the ID which I assume is an auto increment value.  If you want the second row when sorted by ID, you can do a query such as

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable ORDER BY ID LIMIT 1,1
```

To get row 19, you would do

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable ORDER BY ID LIMIT 18,1
```

Use the limit statement back a particular set of rows.  If you want rows 10 through 19, you can use

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable ORDER BY ID LIMIT 9,10
```

In the limit statement, the first number represents the row number (0 based) and the second number is the number of rows to return.

Comment: my scenario: I need to delete only a single row... there are several identical rows.. so using a delete with a where clause would delete all of them. Also, say there are 5 identical rows.. and i need to delete the third of those 5 rows...

Comment: If the five rows are identical, why do you care which one you delete?